# Assign variables to dictionary items with same key

Tags: python, sql-server, python-2.7, dictionary, pymssql

I'm trying to find a way to assign independent variable names to different items in a dictionary. Problem is, all the items use the same key. I'm using `PYMSSQL` to query the DB Server for a list of DB names.

```
conn = pymssql.connect(DBServer, DBUser, DBPass, 'master')
cursor = conn.cursor(as_dict=True)
##print 'On the following prompt, please enter the SQL command you wish to execute.'
##query = raw_input(">>")
cursor.execute("""
Select name from msdb.sys.databases
""")
for row in cursor:
    print row
    print '-----------------------------'

conn.close()
```

This is giving me an output of:

```
{u'name': u'master'}
-----------------------------
{u'name': u'tempdb'}
-----------------------------
{u'name': u'model'}
-----------------------------
{u'name': u'msdb'}
-----------------------------
{u'name': u'MIADMS'}
-----------------------------
{u'name': u'Active'}
-----------------------------
```

As you can see, each item is under the same `name` key. What I'd like to do is assign each entry a specific variable, such as:

```
DB1 = master
DB2 = tempdb
DB3 = mode1
DB4 = msdb
etc...
```

My end goal, is to provide the user a choice of which DB to run further queries against.

Comment: It's probably better to put the names in a list instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly what you asked for:

```
for row in enumerate(cursor):
    exec("DB{0} = row[1][u'name']".format(row[0] + 1))
```

This will dynamically create variables DB1, DB2, ..., DBn

But actually you probably want:

```
x = {"DB{0}".format(row[0] + 1): row[1][u"name"] for row in enumerate(cursor)}
```

which will actually create a dict with keys DB1, DB2, ..., DBn and values holding database names.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to build up a list of the results.

```
names = []
for row in cursor:
    names.append(row["name"])
```

Note that you can do this nicely using a [list comprehension](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw):

```
>>> [row["name"] for row in cursor]
[u'master', u'tempdb', u'model', ...]
```